# HTTP 500 Internal Server Error In App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This code writes in to the datastore

```
    package pack.exp;
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class WriteServlet extends HttpServlet 
    {
         public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws...
     {
    Entity ent= new Entity("Employee", "E");
    ent.setProperty("FirstName", "Agent");
    ent.setProperty("LastName", "47");

    DatastoreService ds= DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    ds.put(ent);

    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("File Saved");
    }
     }
```

This is for reading from datastore

```
     package pack.exp;
     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
     public class ReadServlet extends HttpServlet 
     {
         @Override
      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws  
      {
          super.doGet(req, resp);

          DatastoreService ds= DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

      Key k= KeyFactory.createKey("Employee", "E");

    try 
    {
        Entity ent= ds.get(k);

        String fN= (String) ent.getProperty("FirstName");
        String lN= (String) ent.getProperty("LastName");

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Reading From the Database " + fN );

    }

    catch (EntityNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     }
      }
```

When i am deploying the application the it is showing the appspot page but when my clicking on my Project it is giving HTTP 500 Internal Server Error In App Engine

Comment: possible as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451696/appengine-500-server-error-after-deploy-error-in-code

Comment: I am unable to detect the error.

Comment: what do the error logs say?

Comment: Internal Error       Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for KeyboardFocusManagerPeerProvider [in KeyboardFocusManagerPeerProvider.class [in sun.awt [in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]]]

Comment: Internal Error    Timed out while retrieving the attached javadoc for Agent {key=Lsun/management/Agent;} [in Agent.class [in sun.management [in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar]]]

Answer (score 0):

You're using some part of AWT that isn't supported on GAE (there's no windowing UI to speak of).  Remove that library/package, or whatever package is using it.

BTW, this error should show up on the dev server as well.  You'll save a lot of time testing locally on the dev server before deploying.

Comment: I have used no extra package.

Comment: why is the stack trace saying AWT is being loaded?