# FastAPI app deployed without any errors on gcloud, but the target link gives 500 server error

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, fastapi

I deployed a FastAPI project on google app engine.
Here's my main.py file:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI;
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from app.routes.routes import router as appRoutes;
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get('/')
def root():
    return "Welcome to the fastapi backend"

app.include_router(appRoutes,prefix='/api')
```

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
```

and requirements.txt:

```
fastapi
numpy
uvicorn
scikit-learn
pandas
nltk
gunicorn
pydantic
```

Upon running `gcloud app deploy`, the app is deployed without any errors:

> File upload done. Updating service [default]...done.      Setting
> traffic split for service [default]...done.      Deployed service
> [default] to [.....

when I run `gcloud app browse`, it gives me:

> Did not detect your browser. Go to this link to view your app:

and upon visiting the link I get:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
> complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

I am not really that much into deployment in general so I might be missing out on something.
What exactly is going wrong here? I can't see any error messages...

Edit:
On checking `gcloud app logs tail -s default`

```
2022-09-08 05:57:32 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:32
+0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0 2022-09-08 05:57:32 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (10) 2022-09-08 05:57:32 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker 2022-09-08 05:57:32 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:32 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16 2022-09-08 05:57:32 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:32 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19 2022-09-08 05:57:32 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:32 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20 2022-09-08 05:57:32 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:32 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21 2022-09-08 05:57:34 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0 2022-09-08 05:57:34 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (10) 2022-09-08 05:57:34 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:34 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker 2022-09-08 05:57:34 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:34 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16 2022-09-08 05:57:34 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:34 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19 2022-09-08 05:57:34 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:34 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20 2022-09-08 05:57:34 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:34 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21 2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Handling signal: term 2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 21 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 19 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 16 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 20 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 2022-09-08 05:57:37 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:37 +0000] [10] [INFO] Handling signal: term 2022-09-08 05:57:37 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:37
+0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 21 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:37 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:37
+0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 19 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:37 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:37
+0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 20 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:37 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:37
+0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 16 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:37 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:37
+0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master 2022-09-08 05:57:38 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:38 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0 2022-09-08 05:57:38 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:38 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (11) 2022-09-08 05:57:38 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:38 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker 2022-09-08 05:57:38 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:38 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16 2022-09-08 05:57:38 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:38 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19 2022-09-08 05:57:38 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:38 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20 2022-09-08 05:57:38 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:38 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21 2022-09-08 05:57:41 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:41 +0000] [11] [INFO] Handling signal: term 2022-09-08 05:57:41 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:41 +0000] [11] [WARNING] Worker with pid 16 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:41 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:41 +0000] [11] [WARNING] Worker with pid 19 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:41 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:41 +0000] [11] [WARNING] Worker with pid 20 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:41 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:41 +0000] [11] [WARNING] Worker with pid 21 was terminated due to signal 15 2022-09-08 05:57:41 default[20220908t055413]  [2022-09-08 05:57:41 +0000] [11] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

**The main problem as per my best guess occurs here:**

```
[INFO] Handling signal: term
2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 21 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 19 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 16 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [WARNING] Worker with pid 20 was terminated due to signal 15
2022-09-08 05:57:36 default[20220908t054903]  [2022-09-08 05:57:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Comment: Your app is crashing. Review the log files for error and warning messages. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/viewing-service-logs OR https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging

Comment: Note: your question states Cloud Run, but it appears you are deploying on App Engine. Update your question with the correct details.

Comment: Since you're deploying your App, you should be running ```gcloud app deploy``` and not ```migrate```. To view the errors when you try to load your page, go to ```console.cloud.google.com```, select ```logs explorer``` and look for the error. If you don't understand the error, add it to your post for others to review.

Comment: Are you using the standard or flexible environment? As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15451754/17544309) App Engine 500 (Internal Server Error) almost always means that your Python code threw an unhandled exception that was caught by the runtime.

Look for the Error Reporting panel in the Google Cloud Platform dashboard as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/896597/962416) and share it in your post.

Comment: Your example code is incomplete. Add the missing `app.routes.routes` code. The requirements.txt includes packages that your code does not use. Create a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JohnHanley pardon, I am running indeed deploying on app engine. And I ran `gcloud app deploy` not `migrate`

Comment: @NoCommandLine I ran `gcloud app deploy` and checked the logs, I have updated my question, kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

You have `from app.routes.routes import router as appRoutes;`

1. There is a semicolon (no semicolon in Python)
2. You have `from app.routes` but app is not defined till later (after 1 line) where you have `app = FastAPI()`

In essence, you need to move the line (without the semicolon) `from app.routes.routes import router as appRoutes` to after `app = FastAPI()`