# Google cloud deploying in app engine showing 500 error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I have a FastAPI application that connects to a MySQL database using mysql.connector. When running the application locally, everything works fine, but when I deploy it to App Engine, I get a 502 error. Here's my code:

main.py file \n

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="***",
    user="***",
    password="***",
)

connection = ''
cursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO `dbnae`.`tablename` (`Email`, `FirstName`, `LastName`) VALUES ('johndoe@example.com', 'John', 'Doe')"
success = ""
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    mydb.commit()
    success = "yes"
except:
    mydb.rollback()
    print("Error occurred while inserting data into employees table")

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def home():
    return {"message": "Hello World " + success}
```

app.yaml file

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app
```

requirement.txt

```
astroid==2.3.3
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.3
fastapi==0.47.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
h11==0.9.0
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
pydantic==1.4
pylint==2.4.4
six==1.14.0
starlette==0.12.9
uvicorn==0.11.2
websockets==8.1
wrapt==1.11.2
mysql-connector-python==8.0.32
```

logs are

```
 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/workspace/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'"
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? It's gonna be near impossible to help you just from "I get a 502 error"

Comment: 502 indicates issues with the webserver or proxy or networking. It is very generic and almost impossible to answer without additional details. You need to check out your server logs.

Comment: @harshit gupta, Please let me know if the below recommendations were helpful?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in the app.yaml file you are using 4 workers in the “gunicorn”. Make sure that you have chosen the  required instance class(i.e., more than F4 which is required for 4 workers)  as stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices).

As per the answers from the [Link1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#entrypoint_best_practices) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451696) App Engine Sometimes Logs Error 500 due to issues with the code during the runtime.

The error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'` seems to be a python error. This error occurs if the required module is not installed in the “requirement.txt” file. Make sure you have installed the correct module in the “requirement.txt” file, if not you can install it by using the command `pip install 'module name'`. If you are already installed but still getting the error means check with this [Document](https://itslinuxfoss.com/no-module-named-mysql/) for troubleshooting.

Also check whether the installed packages in the requirements.txt are compatible with your python version you are using.

Also check the [Error Reporting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/check-app-crash) in GCP Console to get the detailed stack trace of the problem in the code.

Also make sure that the “requirements.txt” file is under root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a typo in your post, but the file needs to be called `requirements.txt` not `requirement.txt`. If you misspelled it, Google’s buildpacks will not install your dependencies when you deploy to GAE. You can check the build logs when you deploy to confirm `pip install` is actually running to install your listed dependencies.